# What password is the browser asking with the message ' This site says : Spring '?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-security

I have few Spring Boot projects (developed by other team members). Suddenly after downloading the latest changes (by other developers) from the repository, i started getting the following problem when submitting the form in the application. The browser keeps showing a prompt with the following message and asking for a username and password.

***The site says: "Spring"***

Rest of the developers are saying they don't get this error, i tried creating a new workspace from the latest code in repo and still getting the same error. What User Name and Password is the browser asking for ? Surely this is not my proxy server credentials, because i've tried it but still the prompt keeps coming.

I can see the following error in my Eclipse Console:

```
2015-06-03 04:17:18.736  INFO 5760 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Wed Jun 03 04:17:18 EDT 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
```

Comment: A fairly obvious solution would be to find the commit that introduced this behaviour (`git bisect` if on git) and talk to the author. Not sure what's the question here and how SO audience would be able to help you.

Comment: problem is, none of my team having the latest code is getting this error. and i remember getting a similar problem when trying to run a spring boot application few months back in my personal PC as well. so thought this is something to do with spring/its configuration or browser settings or env variable but, not with the application specific code.